# Can't figure out this type error

Tags: haskell, typeerror

I am still pretty inexperienced at Haskell. That being said, I am having a very hard time finding out where this type the compiler is finding in my code `Maybe (Maybe Int) -> Maybe Int` From what I can tell the only thing that should be returned are Int values.

```
findThisPrime :: Int -> Int
findThisPrime num = calcPrime 1 num
    where calcPrime :: Int -> Int -> Int
          calcPrime curr 0 = curr
          calcPrime curr num = calcPrime (findPrime curr) (num - 1)
          findPrime :: Int -> Int
          findPrime here = (fromMaybe $ find (\x -> isPrime x) [here..])
```

Error:

```
hs> :l projectEuler
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( projectEuler.hs, interpreted )

projectEuler.hs:48:33:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int'
            with actual type `Maybe (Maybe Int) -> Maybe Int'
    In the expression: (fromMaybe $ find (\ x -> isPrime x) [here .. ])
    In an equation for `findPrime':
        findPrime here = (fromMaybe $ find (\ x -> isPrime x) [here .. ])
    In an equation for `findThisPrime':
        findThisPrime num
          = calcPrime 1 num
          where
              calcPrime :: Int -> Int -> Int
              calcPrime curr 0 = curr
              calcPrime curr num = calcPrime (findPrime curr) (num - 1)
              findPrime :: Int -> Int
              findPrime here = (fromMaybe $ find (\ x -> isPrime x) [here .. ])
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

isPrime is a function that takes an Int, checks if it is prime, and returns a Bool.

Comment: The type of `fromMaybe` is `forall . a -> Maybe a -> a`. Therefore, the type of `fromMaybe $ x` is `Maybe a -> a` for some `x :: a`. Regardless of what type `a` is, you can see this already must be a type error - the body of the function `findPrime` must have type `Int`, which it evidently doesn't. You probably want `fromJust` (which handles the Nothing case with an error) because `find isPrime [here..]` is never `Nothing` - the compiler doesn't know this, but of course we do. Or `head $ filter isPrime [here..]`.

Comment: @user2407038: That would have been a nice answer (although some aren't familiar with the explicit `forall a. a -> …`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fromMaybe` expects a fall-back value if the provided `Maybe a` is `Nothing`:

```
fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a
fromMaybe _ (Just x) = x
fromMaybe a Nothing  = a
```

In `findPrime` you're missing that first argument, thus ending up with the wrong type:

```
findPrime here = (fromMaybe $ find (\x -> isPrime x) [here..])
              -- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

We can have a look at the types to verify that this is actually the error:

```
           find (\x -> isPrime x) [here..]  :: Maybe Int
fromMaybe                                   :: a         -> Maybe a           -> a
fromMaybe (find (\x -> isPrime x) [here..]) ::           -> Maybe (Maybe Int) -> Maybe Int
```

Which is exactly the erroneous type you see.

#### Quick solution

If you're certain that `find` will **always** return `Just x`, you can use `fromJust`. Note that `fromJust` is partial, it will throw an exception if you use it on `Nothing`.

Note that `fromJust $ find p xs` is the same as `head $ filter p xs`, which doesn't need additional imports.